How to call function from a dict with its respective args using generics in typescript
So I have a dictionary with functions and the arguments of those functions, like this:
type TypeFnDict = {
   nameOne: {params: Parameters<typeof functionOne>, fn: typeof functionOne},
   nameTwo: {params: Parameters<typeof functionTwo>, fn: typeof functionTwo}
};

const FunctionsDict = {
   nameOne: functionOne,
   nameTwo: functionTwo,
};

function functionOne(a: number, b: number){
   return `${a-b}`;
};

function functionTwo(a: string, b: string, c: number){
   return a+b+`${c}`
};

And what I want is to have another function that accepts the name as a generic and the right parameter for that respective function, calls it and return the result, like this:
createStuff = function<T extends keyof TypeFnDict>(functionName: T, functionParams: TypeFnDict[T]["fn"] ) {
   return FunctionsDict[functionName](...functionParams);
}

But this is not working, I get "A spread argument must either have a tuple type or be passed to a rest parameter.ts(2556)".
I feel like I'm doing something very wrong here, and probably this is a commom mistake. Anyone knows how to do something like this?

The problem is that TS can't reason generically about conditional types like Parameters. The supported way of doing this is to write FunctionsDict explicitly as a mapped type over its keys so that a generically indexed property is seen as a single function type, as described in ms/TS#47109 and demonstrated in this playground link. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer or find a suitable duplication source; if not, what am I missing?

Yes that worked! However, maybe I'm too tired typescripting today, but I'm confused, what exactly does the line 8 in your demo does???
"const FunctionsDict: { [K in keyof FnArgs]: (...args: FnArgs[K]) => FnRet[K] } = _FunctionsDict;"

Your creating a variable equal to another one just to get the types more precise? Why do we need that?

To get the types more precise, yes. Or rather, to get the type in a form TS understands as an operation over generic index K. That way it can plug in K and get a function of type (...args: FnArgs[K]) => FnRet[K], instead of losing track of that and becoming a union of functions, which can only be called with an intersection of arguments. See the linked q/a for more information.

Nice, thank you. Will you write an answer or should I?
